# 'System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler' cannot derive from special class 'System.MulticastDelegate'

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

I'm developing a wcf service as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952692/namespace-differences-between-web-service-and-application-dependency-references/952748#952748). It solved my initial problem of namespace conflicts when developing the original .NET 2.0 web service, but I've come up to another problem.

The object that I'm trying to pass to the wcf service is used in the client to aggregate a bunch of information from the user and some of its fields are databound to ui controls (hence implementing PropertyChangedEventHandler). When I try to compile the proxy generated by svcutil in my client project, I get the error that titles this question.

Pulling all of the data out of this object and putting into into a class for sending (and then reconstructing the original type) would seem redundant - not to mention take a ridiculously long time.

Is there a workaround?

Comment: I'm confused.  You say you are developing a WCF service, but then you say you are developing a .NET 2.0 web service.  WCF is .NET 3.0+, however.  My answer is based on .NET 3.0.

Comment: No, initially it was a .NET 2.0 web service, but the namespace conflict in the 2.0 web service was complicating the design, so I decided to create a wcf service instead (as noted in the link to my other question). Edited to clarify.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can I check? Are you passing a *delegate* to a web service? That won't work... it* cannot be serialized. At best, ADO.NET Data Services (.NET 3.5SP1) can do something similar by translating an `Expression` into a query-string... but that is as close as you'll get. Other than that, you'll have to build a request object that encapsulates your intent with regular properties.

This applies to any of web-service, wcf service, tcp, etc.

*=a delegate is essentially a type-safe method handle (with an optional target (instance) reference); it can be expressed, for example, as xml

---

(edit)

From the comments - it might simply be that you haven't attributed your data-contracts; this means it has to infer the contract (and it often gets it wrong). For example:

```
[DataContract]
class Foo : IWhateverInterfaces {
    [DataMember]
    public string Bar {get;set;}

    [DataMember]
    public int Baz {get;set;}

    public float NotPartOfTheContract {get;set;}

    public event EventHandler AlsoNotPartOfTheContract;
}
```

When using `[DataContract]`, only members marked `[DataMember]` are serialized - so the event should be ignored. This used to be the **only** way of doing WCF data-contracts, but MS tweaked it to infer contracts from fields... a mistake IMO, as it causes the problem you've just had...

Comment: I ended up creating an object called WCFDocument which was just the raw fields that were in my original object (removing any databinding etc.) and made a property in the original object that constructed and returned the a WCFDocument.

... and no, I wasn't passing any delegates. The base class for my object inherited from BindingList<T> and INotifyPropertyChangedEvent.

That's 2 days in a row now that you've helped me. Again, thank you Marc.

Comment: So... if you weren't *explicitly* passing a delegate... I wonder if you simply aren't marking your WCF data-contracts correctly? I couldn't tell juts from the question (since there wasn't any illustrative code). See the edit...

Comment: This helped me. It took awhile to determine the case, but I had ONE single reference to an actual type defined in my wsdl and the rest I had defined as structs etc. I bet if I had more than one, i would have NEVER figured this out, but I created my own type, did a dump foreach and copied it from the wsdl type and poof it works. Thanks.