# Returning a Service reference object in WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have written a core webservice. This webservice handles all the calculations, data operations, etc.

This webservice is in the same solution as my microservice.

My microservice Should communicate with my core webservice, and return the object it received from the core webservice. The problem is that it won't work, as when I start my solution it is unable to translate the reference object for the data contract.

The exception on the WCF test client:

> error CS0644: 'System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler'
> cannot derive from special class 'System.MulticastDelegate'

When I added the COREservice as a reference, It auto-generated classes that implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Now, I of course could write extensive converters that would convert all the objects received from the core webserver to object with the same name, but locally defined, only this would be a lot of work and I doubt there isn't any other faster/more elegant way of solving this.

---

IService:

```
    [OperationContractAttribute(AsyncPattern = true)]
    IAsyncResult BeginOperation(string Salesperson, decimal Timestamp, AsyncCallback asyncCallback, object state);
    CoreWebservice.ReturnObj EndOperation (IAsyncResult result);
```

Service:

```
public CoreWebservice.ReturnObj Operation(string Salesperson = null, decimal? Timestamp = null, OperationContext opContext = null)
{
    CoreWebservice.ReturnObj result = CoreService.Operation(Salesperson, Timestamp ?? default(decimal));

    return result;
}
```

Endpoint:

```
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfServiceLibrary1/Service1/"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_M3ApiCalls"
    contract="COREservice.ApiCalls" name="BasicHttpBinding_M3ApiCalls" />
</client>
```

All the classes or "Resultobjects" are written in the same manner (paired with a result, and a recordresult class)

```
[Serializable()]
[DataContract]
[XmlSerializerFormat()]
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "CRS100MI_List",DataType = "System.Xml.XmlElement",Namespace = "http://www.the.namespace/of/company")]
public class CRS100MI_ListResult
{
    [DataMember]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement(Order = 0)]
    public string Result = "";

    //etc....

    [DataMember]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order = 3)]
    public List<CRS100MI_ListRecordResult> Record = new List<CRS100MI_ListRecordResult>();


    
    public CRS100MI_ListResult Parse(List<Dictionary<string, string>> list)
    {
        //parse a list of dictionaries to fill the fields of the 
        //recordresult, and return the entire object populated with records.

        return this;
    }
}

[Serializable()]
[DataContract(Namespace = "http://www.rexel.nl/M3/ApiCalls")]
[XmlSerializerFormat()]
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "CRS100MI_ListRecord", DataType = "System.Xml.XmlElement", Namespace = "http://www.the.namespace/of/company")]
public class CRS100MI_ListRecordResult
{


    [DataMember]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order = 0)]
    public string Result               { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order = 1)]
    public string ErrorMessage         { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order = 2)]
    public List<string> Messages           { get; set; }

    //etc...

}
```

---

So, to summarize:

1. COREservice is referenced by *service reference* by the MICROservice
2. COREservice returns an object, which is to be returned by the MICROservice
3. MICROservice is dependent on the COREservice
4. Error CS0644 is thrown, because it probably isn't able to derive the full class from the COREservice

   Is this maybe solvable by how I reference to the COREservice? or is there perhaps another solution I have overlooked?

Comment: What is the end point?  For multicast it should be IP.Any not a IP address.   A regular IP address has a mask that will not let Multicast pass.  For example 172.1.1.1 with mask 255.255.255.0 will block multicast.   Using IP.Any does not use mask and will allow all IP to pass.  See also : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3afba67f-56fa-4595-b96d-b1cf06e14a19/multicast-in-wcf?forum=wcf

Comment: @jdweng I have edited the post to show the endpoint of the MICROservice

Comment: Localhost is defined in following file : C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\Hosts.  So you are not using Ip.Any.  It looks like for WCF use IP address 0.0.0.0.  See : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/36f8e497-988f-4174-b4c8-4302d8b69ec6/configure-wcf-to-listen-on-any-adapter?forum=wcf

Comment: Changing the endpoint to 0.0.0.0 did not have any effect unfortunately.

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/creating-multicasting-applications-using-the-udp-transport

Comment: `error CS0644` sounds like a [compiler error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0644) rather than an exception. Can you please clarify if you can compile the application or if this is a runtime problem?

Comment: @SteliosAdamantidis It seems to be a runtime error because it can compile just fine. VisualStudio doesn't throw an error neither, so it seems to be something that is allowed in .net/C# but not in WCF.

Comment: Is event-based async a *must* for you ? Did you try task-based instead ? For one thing, there's no need for event notification, which would eliminate your exception right away, whatever the reason might be; and overall, the generated client code looks much simpler and more robust.

Comment: @jsanalytics The Async aspect is a must, and I currently already have configured the consumption of the Service as Task-based, but still does the reference build the classes with System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged. It also adds "Field" to all the properties of the classes for some reason.

Comment: Sure, i wouldn't question the *async* aspect of it... In fact, i tried both approaches, event-based and task-based, and in neither case could that *cs0644* be replicated... So, unless you're willing to show us how exactly you managed to get that.... there's little hope of any effective help for you... For the record, replicating your situation with a core and a micro service is no problem. Moreover, I'll stick my neck out here and take a wild guess...

Comment: ... if you have "haughty" things like events, event handlers and callbacks all declared and implemented right in the body of your service... DON'T. Instead, implement a class that supports whatever async pattern you want and use that class whithin your service implementation.

Comment: I don't do the chat thing, neither do i want to extend this conversation in the comments section. Turning this into a private consultation between any two users and alienating all the knowledgeable people out there reading this right now wouldn't do any favors to anyone either.... What you shall do is to post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and let anyone who can help do so.

Comment: Alright Thats weird. I have just created a new solution. Added two sevrices with one referencing the other, and it works. Is it perhaps because in my real solution I am also hosting an ASP.NET wep app? is there something i'm overlooking?

Comment: I recommend to have a proxy project that will have reference to COREservice and in this proxy project return your own entity with needed data only that can be used in MICROservice so there will be no direct dependency between generated classes and your MICROservice.

Comment: have you check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957474/system-componentmodel-propertychangedeventhandler-cannot-derive-from-special-c). If it doesn't work try to tick `Reuse types in referenced assemblies` under `Data Type Options`  before adding web service reference. See this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/wcf-web-service-reference-guide) though this is for .net core, I assumed it should have something similar in .net framework.